# Using CSS to create two equal height layout columns, and inserting three equal height stacked columns inside the right column

Tags: html, css, layout, height, equals

[image: example picture]

I can't use the table tag nor flexbox.  Most of our visitors are elderly people using IE8.

I am trying to create two equal height layout columns that floats on the left and right.

The left column contains two stacked div that is not equal height. but these divs should expand to fill the total height of the col1.

The right column contains three stacked columns that should have equal heights. these div should also fill in the total height of the col2.

In overall, col1 and col2 should always have the equal height.

I can't set up fixed px size for each columns as contents that go inside can be different everyday. i would like both col1 and col2 contents to expand to fit in the total height so there is no left over space at the bottom.

My option was to use display: table; but if you have some good suggestions, please let me know.

(Just for your reference, all div shown in the image have a border.)

```
<div class="container">

 <div class="left">
  <div class="col-1-1"></div>
  <div class="col-1-2"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="right">
  <div class="col-2-1"></div>
  <div class="col-2-2"></div>
  <div class="col-2-3"></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richard Sussans answer is right, but you need to float the columns (both left) in order to make them appear next to eachother. You also need to specify a height for the columns (as well as their parent elements, assuming the height is set in %) for their children to expand vertically. With your markup, the following css should do the trick:

```
html, body, .container {
    height: 100%;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 35%;
}

.right {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 65%;
}

.col-1-1 {
    height: 25%;
}

.col-1-2 {
    height: 75%;
}

.col-2-1 {
    height: 33%;
}

.col-2-2 {
    height: 33%;
}

.col-2-3 {
    height: 34%;
}
```

Comment: ... and you only need to specify the width of the columns, as opposed to each element. The .col* elements will take up 100% of their parent's width.
Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use al of those percentages in css for height and width and it will adjust to the user's screen size!

These may not work exactly perfectly, you can always fiddle with the numbers or try another way.
Hope this helps

```
.left {
    height: 100%
    width: 35%
}

.right {
    height: 100%
    width: 65%
}

.col-1-1 {
{
    height: 25%
    width: 35%
}

.col-1-2 {
{
    height: 75%
    width: 35%
}

.col-2-1 {
{
    height: 33%
    width: 65%
}

.col-2-2 {
{
    height: 33%
    width: 65%
}

.col-2-3 {
{
    height: 34%
    width: 65%
}
```

Comment: Would it be necessary to set the display mode as "table" and assign "table-row" for div class left and right, and assign display to "table-cell" to all col-x-x columns?  Or can I just use it on div display set to block?

Comment: No tables necessary, i think the table may make it more complicated than you need. Just use the divs like you have written in your question

Comment: thank you for your answer.  I floated .left to float:left, and .right to float:right.  Tried the css, and any inner divs (.col-x-x) don't expands to assigned height. You could see the picture here: https://s32.postimg.org/44bf2qi4l/pro2.gif  I wonder what I am doing wrong :/